# Stripe and Parse Cloud Code charge credit card

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

This is the NSDictionary that I'm passing in when calling PFCloud

[image]

this is my parse cloud code, and it always crashes when I try to charge the card. I'm sure that I have the token, and I think the error is coming from the "amount" when I tried to set it. I used "request.params.cost" and "item.get('cost') and even just put in a value like what I have in the image, they still give me errors

[image]

I'm not sure where I did wrong. I followed the ParseStore project and read through all the code. I just don't get why it always crashes when it tries to charge the credit card... 
I have the correct "stripe secret key" as well.

Comment: what error message are you getting in the cloud code log?

Comment: Sorry I was trying to post an image to show the error message, but stack overflow only allowed me to post 2 images.
and the error message was saying "Object [object Object] has no method 'isString' at request"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is right. I was running into the same issue and reported it to [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1024338347618594/).

Next time, I recommend you post more of your code as formatted text, as you will get more search engine hits :)

Comment: Thank you for the advice. It's like my first or second time posting question and not really sure how to do it. 

Also, I figured out that instead of entering 100, if I do 100.00, it'd work.... haha.